# Eloquent many to many relationship is always empty

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, many-to-many

I know this question has been asked a lot but all answers didn't seem to work for me - or at least the questions I found were about the pivot table.

I have a many to many relationship (User - Appointment) which is joined by the pivot table "apointment_user", see migrations below.

```
Schema::create('appointment_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
   $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
   $table->unsignedInteger('appointment_id')->nullable();
   $table->foreign('appointment_id')->references('id')->on('appointments');
   $table->primary(['user_id','appointment_id']);
   $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('appointments', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('title');
  $table->dateTime('date');
  $table->string('location');
  $table->dateTime('departure');
  $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('email')->unique();
  $table->string('password');
  $table->date('last_login')->nullable();
  $table->rememberToken();
  $table->timestamps();
  $table->softDeletes();
});

class User extends Model {
  protected $with = ['appointments'];
  public function appointments() : BelongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Appointment::class);
  }
}

class Appointment extends Model {
  public function users() : BelongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
  }
}
```

I have a user with the ID `1` and about 10 appointments, which I do attach to the relationship in a seeder. The pivot table has 10 records, as intended (User ID is always `1`).

However, if I dump my User object using `dd(User::find(1))`, the relationship is always an empty collection. However, a 1:n relationship (between a role works well).

Does anybody see what I'm missing? Any help is appreciated.
Many thanks and kind regards

---

## Edit

I just tried some other kind of dumping. I've simply returned my User-Object as JSON-response and there the relationship is filled with 10 appointments... strange.

Comment: You should let Laravel define foreign keys automatically, rather than enforcing them.
Also, I don't get the point of inheriting from BelongsToMany: `public function users() : BelongsToMany`.

It seems to me that your manual approach made Laravel ommit key functionality and didn't setup the relations for you.

Comment: @JCode the use of the `public function name(): someType` just enforcs/specify that the returned element matches thae `someType` type/class (`string` or `User` for example). Check [this example](https://3v4l.org/JXlnA).

Comment: On the other hand, @PaddaelsM, I don't get what are you asking, it seems that you aready resolved it (?).

Comment: @HCK It's also obsolete and might be the source of his problems.

`public function users() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\User') }` is sufficient.

Comment: @JCode not at all. Actually is a PHP `7.0+` feature. Check [this list](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-type-hinting.html). This shouldn't have any impact on his issue. We don't have further info about how is he making his queries or how is he printing them out.. it seems already solved his problem

Comment: @HCK You are right.

Comment: @HCK no, sorry. I didn't solve it. It was  just something I came across. I'm still not able to use a foreach loop on my appointments, even though they clearly exist.

Comment: @PaddaelsM put the related code about how are making the query and dumping the data.

Answer (score 0):

Though it seems that your table and column names are as Laravel would guess, have you tried expliciting the names?

```php
class User extends Model {
  protected $with = ['appointments'];
  public function appointments() : BelongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Appointment::class, 'appointment_user', 'user_id', 'appointment_id');
  }
}

class Appointment extends Model {
  public function users() : BelongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'appointment_user', 'appointment_id', 'user_id');
  }
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, I've done this as well but I will check again on thursday. Many thanks.